# How to show image loaded with Picasso after popBackStack()

Tags: android, android-fragments, imageview, picasso

I have the first fragment which has an imageView loaded in this way with Picasso:

```
 ExifInterface exif = null;
                float rotate = 0;

                try
                {
                    exif = new ExifInterface(absolutePath);
                } catch (IOException e)
                {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                int orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION,
                        ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_UNDEFINED);
                switch (orientation) {
                    case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL:
                        rotate = 0;
                        break;
                    case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
                        rotate = 270;
                        break;
                    case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
                        rotate = 180;
                        break;
                    case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
                        rotate = 90;
                        break;
                }


                Picasso.with(getActivity())
                        .load(mMediaUri)
                        .resize(1280, 1280)
                        .rotate(rotate)
                        .centerCrop()
                        .transform(new RoundedTransformation())
                        .into(photo);
```

when I press `next` button I do this and I go to the second fragment:

```
      Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                              bundle.putLong("primaryKey", primaryKey);
                              bundle.putString("uri", String.valueOf(mMediaUri));
                              bundle.putString("registration", registrationET.getText().toString().trim());
                              bundle.putString("makemodel", makemodelET.getText().toString().trim());
                              bundle.putString("manifacturer", manifacturerET.getText().toString().trim());
                              bundle.putString("category", categoryET.getText().toString().trim());
                              bundle.putString("class", classET.getText().toString().trim());

                              Fragment fragment = new AddAircraftSecondPartFragment();
                              fragment.setArguments(bundle);

                              FragmentManager manager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
                              manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_main, fragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();
```

The issue happens when I want to press back or I click on the `Back` button: values on `EditText` or `TextView` are in the right way because I use this:

```html
android:freezesText="true"
```

but I don't see the previous image loaded with Picasso in ImageView.
This is the code I've used to `popBackStack()`:

```
 private void pressBackButton()
{
    FragmentManager manager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();

    manager.popBackStack();

}
```

so my question are:

1. how could I solve the issue of ImageView?
2. what's the method called in the previous fragment after `popBackStack()` ?

Thank you for answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) You can move your image loading to overridden onResume() method of your fragment.

2) onResume() is called when fragment is "resumed"